# How to wait for all completionHandler blocks to complete before proceeding?

Tags: ios, concurrency, google-drive-api, objective-c-blocks

Have been using the `Google Drive iOS SDK`, and trying to build a list of folder contents, which includes the folder parent-folders & sub-folders.

The Google Drive iOS SDK stuff is simple enough, but given the sample code below, how do I wait for all "**queryForFilesGetWithFileId**" completionHandler blocks to complete before proceeding?

The reason is that addFolderChildren adds the sub-folders & then refreshes the view, which obviously needs to be done last.

```
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForParentsListWithFileId:folderId];
[self.driveService executeQuery:query
              completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                  GTLDriveParentList *parents,
                                  NSError *error)
 {
     if (error == nil)
     {
         for (GTLDriveParentReference *parent in parents)
         {
             if ([parent.isRoot intValue] == 1)
             {
                 // add folder root -> "My Drive"
             }
             else
             {
                 GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesGetWithFileId:parent.identifier];
                 [self.driveService executeQuery:query
                               completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                   GTLDriveFile *file,
                                                   NSError *error)
                  {
                      if (error == nil)
                      {
                          // add folder parent -> file.title
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          [self handleFailed:error];
                      }
                  }];
             }
         }
         // add folder children
         // how do we wait here until all above queryForFilesGetWithFileId completionhandler blocks are done?
         [self addFolderChildren:folderId];
     }
     else
     {
         [self handleFailed:error];
     }
 }];
```

Comment: You can keep an index for parents count and decrease 1 at completion. Then you can update your ui when you reach to 0.

Comment: Thanks @BoranA, nice workaround until I'm able to tame NSOperation/Queue, GCD etc. for an elegant solution.

Comment: Ok then, this the more elegant one. Subclass NSOperation, create a property for your completion block. Create an operation queue and set maxconcurrency to 1 and add your operations to the queue. If you want to be sure about the fifo order you should set priorities or dependencies of the queue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use @protocol for this

like

```
@protocol MeuDelegate <NSObject>
@optional

-(void) meuEditingDone:(Meu*) meu;

@end


@interface EditMeu : MeuBasicViewController {

    id <MeuDelegate> delegate;
}


@property (retain) id delegate;

@end
```

and in the .m file do followings

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

call this method in your completion handler , so form there you can proceeds.